# Using Klein-PHP to filter requests

Tags: php, routes

I am using Klein.php for routing in my PHP project. My project directory has following structure:

```
myProject
|
*---Restricted--
|              |
|              *---index.php
|              |
|              *---blah.html
|              |
|              *---some_directory
|
|
*---some_other_directories
|
*---index.html
|
*---fun.html
|
*---css
|
*---js
```

What I want is to process all request to the `Restricted` folder only. For everything else I simply want the server to do its job, i.e. simply serve rest of the files.

How do I achieve that?

**Edit**

I have it configured as give in answer by CORY:

```
// .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

and

```
// index.php

<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $klein = new \Klein\Klein();

    $klein->respond('@^/Restricted/', function () {
       // checking if authenticated user
    });

    $klein->dispatch();

?>
```

Comment: How do you currently have it configured?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Request to say, `blah.html` should be forwarded to index.php but for files like `fun.html` it should simply be served. Right now only those links work which have some matching rule defined in index.php and for rest I see a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right on the [Github page for `Klein.php`](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php#routing) there's this little example in the **Routing** section:

```
// Match all requests that _don't_ start with /admin
$klein->respond('!@^/admin/', ...
```

I think you basically want the *opposite* (match all requests that **do** start with `/restricted`), so let's remove the `!` (negation) and substitute the right folder name:

```
// Match all requests that start with /Restricted
$klein->respond('@^/Restricted/', ...
```